# DPDK multiple distributor

Tags: dpdk

I have some problem with using DPDK distributor.

I have 2 lcore_rx threads and 4 worker threads.

I have 2 RX queue and each lcore_rx thread will get packet with `rte_eth_rx_burst`

after burst packet, I want set packet to each distributor (ex. dist[0], dist[1]).

Then 1~4 worker thread will get packet from distributor like below.

1~2 worker will request to dist[0]

3~4 worker will request to dist[1]

I Think this should be work, but only 1~2 worker work fine.

3~4 worker and second lcore_rx thread not working after few packet(10~20 packets)

It looks like dead-lock.

It is possible to use multiple distributor??

Answer (score 1):

The question should be more clear. Did you use soft RSS or HW RSS?
let's assume you used HW RSS, and configured 2 rx queues.
now your 2 polling threads aka DPDK rx processes should poll from these 2 rx queues separately.

```
//from 1st rx process (rx_thread_0)
rte_eth_rx_burst(port,0, ...); 

// from 2nd rx process (rx_thread_1)
rte_eth_rx_burst(port,1, ...);
```

this should be fine. but if you try to poll from the same rx queue from more than 1 rx process it will need a lock mechanism which is why you should poll separately. if you configure 4 rx queue, then your 2 rx process can poll from these by 1st rx process polling from 0,1 queues, and 2nd rx process polling from 2,3 queues. but not the same Rx queue from the 2 processes.

and then your RX processes are putting those packets on a rte_ring right? make sure that 1 rte_ring has 1 producer and 1 consumer, otherwise, you have to configure the rte_ring differently (though it didn't work in my case). so if you have 2 rx processes and 4 worker processes, it's best to use 4 rte_rings. Make your first 2 rx processes enqueueing the packets to rte_ring 0 & 1, and second rx processes enqueueing the packets to rte_ring 2 & 3.

```
//from rx_thread_0
rte_ring_enqueue_bulk(rte_ring_0,...)
rte_ring_enqueue_bulk(rte_ring_1,...)

//from rx_thread_1
rte_ring_enqueue_bulk(rte_ring_2,...)
rte_ring_enqueue_bulk(rte_ring_3,...)
```

Then your 4 working processes should poll from this 4 rte_ring independently with the highest possible throughput at high speed.

```
//from working thread_0
rte_ring_dequeue_burst(rte_ring_0,...)

//from working thread_1
rte_ring_dequeue_burst(rte_ring_1,...)

//from working thread_2
rte_ring_dequeue_burst(rte_ring_2,...)

//from working thread_3
rte_ring_dequeue_burst(rte_ring_3,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dpdk framework requires that one rxq can only run on one PMD lcore at the same time, and multiple pmd polls need to lock rxq to avoid multi-core competition

> Multiple logical cores should never share receive or transmit queues
> for interfaces since this would require global locks and hinder
> performance.

https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-23.07/prog_guide/poll_mode_drv.html#logical-cores-memory-and-nic-queues-relationships